# Trying to reverse list of strings gives individual characters

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
test = "\n".join(["gym", "meetup", "Christian associations"])
print(sorted(test, reverse=True))
```

Can someone please explain why I'm getting the following below, instead of reverse of the above list. It's weird how this long list of gibberish appeared.

```
['y', 'u', 't', 't', 't', 's', 's', 's', 's', 'r', 'p', 'o', 'o', 'n', 'n', 'm', 'm', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'h', 'g', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'C', ' ', '\n', '\n']
```

Comment: Why are you trying to join the list? This creates a string for the variable `test`. Based on your code, it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Try adding what your expected output would be.

Comment: Are you trying to *sort* the list too? If not, why did you use `sorted`? But yeah, the problem is you are `.join`ing the list... why are you doing that? It's hard to discern what you were *expecting*. In any case, that output isn't weird at all, it's **exactly what you would expect** if you joined that list into a new-line sperated string, then called `sorted` on it...

Comment: `"\n".join(["gym", "meetup", "Christian associations"])` produces the single string `'gym\nmeetup\nChristian associations'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation for your code:

You first line produces the following string: `"gym\nmeetup\nChristian associations"`
Your second line takes previous string as list of characters, sorts characters by their unicode value and returns a list of characters.

Hope that's clear.

Are you trying to achieve something like this:

```
print('\n'.join(sorted(["gym", "meetup", "Christian associations"], reverse=True)))
```

Output:

```
meetup
gym
Christian associations
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reverse list you can try with this code,

```
test  = ["gym", "meetup", "Christian associations"]
test.reverse()
print(test)
```

In your code, you combined a list to string. Then, pass that string to sort function, that sorts the alphabets of string, not the elements of the list.